# WPF: Auto truncating text in RadRichTextBox

Tags: wpf, telerik, richtextbox, texttrimming

I am using Telerik's RadRichTextBox control in WPF application, in which I wanted to do TextTrimming for the long sentence/string/text. Like for below screen shot-

[image]

But I found there is no support for "TextTrimming" for RadRichTextBox control by Telerik. Can anyone suggest how we can do that?

Comment: Did you try to set the `LayoutMode` to `Flow`?

Comment: @mm8, yes I tried, but it is not my solution. I need to do TextTrimming.